# Pasar una función de validación fecha combobox JavaScript a Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

Tengo la siguiente función `javascript` que valida las fechas de una `combobox` dentro de un formulario:

```
function asignaDias() {
        comboDias = document.formFecha.seleccionaDia;
        comboMeses = document.formFecha.seleccionaMes;
        comboAnyos = document.formFecha.seleccionaAnyo;



        Month = comboMeses[comboMeses.selectedIndex].text;
        Year = comboAnyos[comboAnyos.selectedIndex].text;


        diasEnMes = cuantosDias(Month, Year);
        diasAhora = comboDias.length - 1;
        debugger;
        if (diasAhora > diasEnMes) {
            for (i = 0; i < (diasAhora - diasEnMes) ; i++) {
                comboDias.options[comboDias.options.length - 1] = null

            }
        }
        if (diasEnMes > diasAhora) {
            for (i = 0; i < (diasEnMes - diasAhora) ; i++) {
                sumaOpcion = new Option(comboDias.options.length);
                comboDias.options[comboDias.options.length] = sumaOpcion;
                console.log("<br> dias: " + sumaOpcion + ", ");
            }
        }
        if (comboDias.selectedIndex < 0)
            comboDias.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Quiero transformar la función a `Jquery`. El objetivo es para que la validación de los `combobox` fecha no funcionen solamente dentro de un formulario, sino que se pueda referenciar a través del `class` o del `id`. Estoy tratando de hacerlo funcionar con el nombre que le asigné a un `class` usando `Jquery`. Lo intento de la siguiente forma:

```
function asignaDias() {
        //comboDias = document.formFecha.seleccionaDia;
        //comboMeses = document.formFecha.seleccionaMes;
        //comboAnyos = document.formFecha.seleccionaAnyo;

        comboDias = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Dia option");
        comboMeses = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Mes").val();
        comboAnyos = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Anio").val();

        dias_index = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Dia').index()

        Month = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Mes').text();
        Year = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Anio').text();

        diasEnMes = cuantosDias(Month, Year);
        diasAhora = comboDias.length - 1;
        debugger;
        if (diasAhora > diasEnMes) {
            for (i = 0; i < (diasAhora - diasEnMes) ; i++) {
                comboDias[comboDias.length - 1] = null

            }
        }
        if (diasEnMes > diasAhora) {
            for (i = 0; i < (diasEnMes - diasAhora) ; i++) {
                sumaOpcion = new Option(comboDias.length);
                comboDias[comboDias.length] = sumaOpcion;
                console.log("<br> dias: " + sumaOpcion + ", ");
            }
        }
        if (dias_index < 0)
            dias_index = 0;
    }
```

En Jquery no me funciona. Debe haber un problema de traspaso de lenguaje, en especial cuando se usaba el “option”.

Incluyo los `combobox`:

```
  <form name="formFecha">
    <select class="fecha_Nacimiento_Dia" name="seleccionaDia">
        <option>-</option>
        <% For i As Integer = 1 To 31%>
        <option value="<%=i%>"><%=i%></option>
        <%Next%>
    </select>
    <select class="fecha_Nacimiento_Mes" name="seleccionaMes" onchange="asignaDias()">
        <option value="">-</option>
            <% Dim mes_j As Integer = 1
            For Each mes As String In Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames%>            
            <option value="<%: mes_j%>"><%= Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(mes)%></option>
            <% mes_j = mes_j + 1
            If mes_j = 13 Then
                Exit For
            End If
            Next%>
    </select>
    <select class="fecha_Nacimiento_Anio" name="seleccionaAnyo"  onchange="asignaDias()">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            document.write(rellenaAnyos(90));
        </script>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Como nota: jQuery es JavaScript. Para hacer más genérica la función, no necesitas utilizar jQuery, te bastaría con cambiar los selectores en la función original y debería ir igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una alternativa usando jQuery. Estos son algunos de los cambios que he hecho:

- `comboDias` hace referencia a la select y no a las opciones de dentro

  - Esto es lo que hace que mucho del código de arriba no funcione, en unas partes usas `comboDias` como la lista de las opciones y en otras lo usas como el combobox. **Sólo corrigiendo esto ya funcionará tu código**.
- Me he alejado un poco de la notación JavaScript puro para borrar/crear/atravesar las opciones.

  - No hay necesidad de usar los corchetes y los índices, si lo vas a hacer con jQuery, hazlo con jQuery (selecciona con `find`, atraviesa con `each`) en lugar de usar corchetes, bucles e índices que son un poco más "oscuros" y no se ve tan bien qué es lo que hace.

El nuevo código de la función quedaría así:

```
function asignaDias() {

    comboDias = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Dia");
    comboMeses = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Mes").val();   // esto realmente no se necesita
    comboAnyos = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Anio").val();  // esto realmente no se necesita

    dias_index = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Dia').index()

    Month = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Mes').text();
    Year = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Anio').text();

    diasEnMes = cuantosDias(Month, Year);
    diasAhora = comboDias.find("option").length - 1;  // calcula el numero de dias

    debugger;
    if (diasAhora > diasEnMes) {
        comboDias.find("option").each(function() { 
            if ($(this).attr("value") > diasEnMes)
                $(this).remove();
        });
    }
    if (diasEnMes > diasAhora) {
        for (i = diasAhora+1; i <= diasEnMes ; i++) {
            comboDias.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + "</option>");
        }
    }

    if (dias_index < 0)
        dias_index = 0;
}
```

Y aquí puedes ver cómo funciona (me he inventado un código simplificado para `cuantosDias`, para probarlo cambia de Febrero a otro mes para ver los resultados):

```js
// solo para Demo
function cuantosDias(m, y) {
  if (m == "Febrero") {
    return 28;
  } else {
    return 31;
  }
}
function asignaDias() {

  comboDias = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Dia");
  comboMeses = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Mes").val();   // esto realmente no se necesita
  comboAnyos = $(".fecha_Nacimiento_Anio").val();  // esto realmente no se necesita

  dias_index = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Dia').index()

  Month = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Mes').text();
  Year = $('option:selected', '.fecha_Nacimiento_Anio').text();

  diasEnMes = cuantosDias(Month, Year);
  diasAhora = comboDias.find("option").length - 1;  // calcula el numero de dias

  debugger;
  if (diasAhora > diasEnMes) {
    comboDias.find("option").each(function() { 
      if ($(this).attr("value") > diasEnMes)
        $(this).remove();
    });
  }
  if (diasEnMes > diasAhora) {
    for (i = diasAhora+1; i <= diasEnMes ; i++) {
      comboDias.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + "</option>");
    }
  }

  if (dias_index < 0)
    dias_index = 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formFecha">
  <select class="fecha_Nacimiento_Dia" name="seleccionaDia">
    <option>-</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
  <select class="fecha_Nacimiento_Mes" name="seleccionaMes" onchange="asignaDias()">
    <option value="">-</option>         
    <option value="1">Enero</option>
    <option value="2">Febrero</option>
    <option value="3">Marzo</option>
  </select>
  <select class="fecha_Nacimiento_Anio" name="seleccionaAnyo"  onchange="asignaDias()">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

---

Y por si no quieres usar jQuery, aquí te dejo una función equivalente a la que he puesto arriba, sólo que usando JavaScript puro (y preservando algo del código original que posteaste):

```
function asignaDias() {

    comboDias = document.querySelector(".fecha_Nacimiento_Dia");

    dias_index = document.querySelector('.fecha_Nacimiento_Dia option:checked').value;

    Month = document.querySelector('.fecha_Nacimiento_Mes option:checked').innerHTML;
    Year = document.querySelector('.fecha_Nacimiento_Anio option:checked').innerHTML;

    diasEnMes = cuantosDias(Month, Year);
    diasAhora = comboDias.querySelectorAll("option").length - 1;  // calcula el numero de dias

    //debugger;
    if (diasAhora > diasEnMes) {
        comboDias.querySelectorAll("option").forEach(function(elemento, indice, arreglo) { 
            if (elemento.value > diasEnMes) 
                comboDias.removeChild(elemento);
        });
    }
    if (diasEnMes > diasAhora) {
        for (i = diasAhora+1; i <= diasEnMes ; i++) {
            sumaOpcion = new Option(i);
            comboDias[i] = sumaOpcion;
            console.log("<br> dias: " + sumaOpcion + ", ");
        }
    }

    if (dias_index < 0)
        dias_index = 0;
}
```